# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/vfs/FileSystemException

Tags: java, sftp

An odd thing happened after I followed sample code from here

**Code**

```
try {
    String filePath="C:\\srcFolder\\" + fileName;
    String destFolder="\\destFolder";
    int status = SFTP.sendFile(filePath, destFolder, ftpServer, ftpUserName, ftpPassword);
    if(FileTransferStatus.SUCCESS == status){
        System.out.println(filePath + " got sftp-ed successfully to  folder "+destFolder);
    }
    else if(FileTransferStatus.FAILURE == status){
        System.out.println("Fail to ssftp  to  folder "+destFolder);
    }
} catch (FileTransferException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/vfs/FileSystemException
    at com.zehon.sftp.SFTP.getSFTPClient(SFTP.java:20)
    at com.zehon.sftp.SFTP.sendFile(SFTP.java:50)
    at uploadFile(ftpService.java:208)
```

EDIT:
I included the jar in the Eclipse project external libraries and I still get the same error 
also, I am using Maven

Comment: Did you include `commons-vfs-1.0.jar` in the runtime classpath?

Comment: This isn't odd. The runtime is complaining about not finding a particular class. You should find out the jar which contains it and add the same to your application classpath.

Comment: i included the jar in the Eclipse project external libraries and i still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put commons-vfs-1.0.jar into your classpath to the specific project and make sure all imports are there in the Java classes

Comment: i just did that, and i still get the same `vfs/FileSystemError`

Comment: since youre running maven, ensure that you have the dependency in the correct pom.xml